# jQuery element height calculation behaving unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

New to playing with jQuery and javascript (and stackOverflow). My project is basically a scrolling page with linked divs.

For aesthetic reasons, I wold like to have each div fill the size of window and I decided that jQuery would be an easy way to do this. The basic structure is this:

> **IF** the div is shorter than the window
>
> **THEN** grow to the size of the window.
>
> **ELSE** use an auto height

I can get a single div to behave this way, the problem is I am applying this to a class and the other objects do not seem to want to behave in the same manner. Here is a fiddle (first time making a fiddle so if the link is not working let me know -

http://jsfiddle.net/ksaiyo/VBMVQ/3/

This fiddle shows the exact opposite:

http://jsfiddle.net/ksaiyo/6YYFU/1/

My script is here, but the fiddle seems to show the effect well enough. The heights stay at the auto height. (I  have a fixed navigation header and unelegantly used padding on top so the linked elements in the page line up correctly - thus the extraneous variables)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var divHeight = $( ".content" ).height();
var winHeight = $( window ).height();
var headerHeight = $( "header" ).height();
var viewHeight = winHeight - headerHeight
var newHeight = winHeight + headerHeight;


if (divHeight <= viewHeight ) {
    $( ".content" ).height(newHeight);
};
)}
```

I have searched around and I can't seem to nail down the exact reason to why this is occurring. I tried to use an **else** statement in conjunction, but then everything including the small elements adopt the auto height. (I tried it in the fiddle as well)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You appear to have a syntax error in your JSFiddle. Reverse the last curly brace and parenthesis to fix this, and your script seems to do what you need it to. http://jsfiddle.net/VBMVQ/4/

Comment: In the fiddle you posed, all the heights were the SAME, so now all the divs use the calculated height, and larger elements get truncated

Comment: Don't use jquery for this, you can do it with one line of css - min-height: 100vh

Comment: Perfect! I feel like a dummy.

Comment: Alternatively, if legacy browser support is important, you can use the jQuery `.each()` to iterate through each `.content` element. http://jsfiddle.net/VBMVQ/5/ (Before you were only checking a single one and comparing it against the height of the viewport, which is why the tall one was ignored.)

Comment: @Greg Except vh has really buggy support in mobile Safari. If you were to actually use vh, you would have to use something like this [buggyfill](https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill).

Comment: @Serlite Thanks for the tip! I love how easy jQuery is to pick up - I will definitely be playing more with it in the future.

Comment: @RyanMitchell I will look into buggyfill, I read somewhere support for vh was spotty - it just so darn convenient.